# How to embed a text file in a Python package and access it properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, resources, package, embedded-resource

I would like to include a textual resource file (to store a complex SQL request code) within a subpackage of my Python 3.6 package and read it (as a string, a collection of strings or as a file, whatever) in runtime. How can this possibly be done?

Answer (score 1):

Why store it outside your code ? Python has multline strings so if it's just a matter of readability, you don't need a distinct text file:

```
# mydbcode.py

# not really complex actually but you get the point...    
complex_query = """
SELECT   GROUPS.PGROUP, SUM(P.AMOUNT)
FROM     PENALTIES AS P,
        (SELECT 1 AS PGROUP, '1980-01-01' AS START,
                '1981-06-30' AS END
         UNION
         SELECT 2, '1981-07-01', '1982-12-31'
         UNION
         SELECT 3, '1983-01-01', '1984-12-31') AS GROUPS
WHERE    P.PAYMENT_DATE BETWEEN START AND END
GROUP BY GROUPS.PGROUP
ORDER BY 1
"""
```

Now if you *really* want to have it in a .sql file in the package using it, well it's just a matter of locating the file and reading it. The only "difficulty" here is locating the file, but you can use the `__file__` magic variable and `os.path` functions to get it:

```
# mydbcode.py
import os
_HERE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
_SQLFILE = os.path.join(_HERE, "myquery.sql")

def read_query():
    with open(_SQLFILE) as f:
        return f.read().strip()
```

Comment: Why store it outside the code? I just love to keep my projects organization as granular as possible and the code files as small as possible, big code files harm my productivity (because of ADHD). I really wish I could put every function in a separate file without having to add to many extra import statements...